# jQuery -> AJAX -> PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I've been searching and searching, but unfortunately I can't find any answers that relates to my problem.

I'm having trouble to read data that I've sent through jQuery (ajax) in my PHP script.

jQuery:

```
$('.sendOrder').click(function(){
    if (validateForm() == true) {

        (function($){
            var convertTableToJson = function()
                {
                    var rows = [];
                    $('table#productOverview tr').each(function(i, n){
                        var $row = $(n);
                        rows.push ({

                            productId:  $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                            product:    $row.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                            size:       $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                            price:      $row.find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                            quantity:   $row.find('td:eq(4)').text(),
                        });
                    });
                    var orderObj = [];
                    orderObj.push({
                        name: $("#customerName").val(),
                        email: $("#customerEmail").val(),
                        phone: $("#customerPhone").val(),
                        order: rows
                    });
                    return orderObj;
                    console.log(orderObj);
                }
            $(function(){
                request = $.ajax({
                    url: 'shop/sendData.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify(convertTableToJson()),
                    success: function(ret) {
                        console.log(ret);
                    }
                });
```

When I'm looking at Chrome it seems to be sent correctly with json:

```
    [  
   {  
      "name":"Kristian",
      "email":"kristian@example.com",
      "phone":"12345678",
      "order":[  
         {  
            "productId":"Prod #",
            "product":"Produkt",
            "size":"Str",
            "price":"Pris",
            "quantity":"Antall"
         },
         {  
            "productId":"09",
            "product":"Bokser",
            "size":"2 meter (249kr)",
            "price":"249,- eks mva",
            "quantity":"1 stk"
         },
         {  
            "productId":"09",
            "product":"Bokser",
            "size":"2 meter (249kr)",
            "price":"249,- eks mva",
            "quantity":"1 stk"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

In my sendData.php I've got it pretty plain:

```
<?PHP header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

The return I'm getting are:

`[]`

What am I doing wrong? What have I forgotten?

Comment: First things first: simply place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data printed to the screen. Familiarize yourself with how form data is posted to scripts, including what gets passed and what doesn't.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: And for now, get rid of the `header()`

Comment: How about you don't use JSON.stringify in your javascript, and then in your php use print_r( $_POST)?

Comment: Remove this from your AJAX request `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`

Comment: don't you want to *de*code the json? not *en*code it? On a side note - I wouldn't be passing personally identifiable information in plain text format.

Comment: you could try to force the JSON in PHP to an object JSON_FORCE_OBJECT http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using file_get_contents("php://input") instead of post.

I.e

```
function isValidJSON($str) {
   json_decode($str);
   return json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE;
}

$json_params = file_get_contents("php://input");

if (strlen($json_params) > 0 && isValidJSON($json_params)) {
  $decoded_params = json_decode($json_params);

echo $decoded_params[0]->name;
}
```

Returned "Kristian"

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` expects an identifier. In your AJAX you'll have to supply one, for example:

```
request = $.ajax({
              url: 'shop/sendData.php',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              // note the change here, adding 'json' as the name or identifier
              data: { json: JSON.stringify(convertTableToJson())},
              success: function(ret) {
                    console.log(ret);
                }
           });
```

Then you should be able to see the JSON string in `$_POST['json']`